# Django admin inline table not posting values to one to one relationship

Tags: python, django, signals, inline, models

sorry for the convoluted question but I am a uni student who has been thrown into the Django framework without any training and I'm doing my best to understand all this in a short time. I really enjoy Django but just can't figure out one problem I'm having.

So for the assignment, I need to extend the default admin users table to include more fields. This is what i've done:

models:

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userTypeID = models.ForeignKey(UserType)
    dob = models.DateField()
    contactNumber = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserInfo.objects.create(user=instance)
        UserInfo.save(instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.userinfo.save()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)
```

admin:

```
class UserInfoInline(admin.StackedInline):
model = UserInfo

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserInfoInline, )

admin.site.register(UserType)
admin.site.register(City)
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

This brings up the extra fields in the admin panel which is what i was looking for. However, when i try to add a new user and I select one of the userTypes (the OneToOneField), I get:

> IntegrityError at /admin/auth/user/add/
>   (1048, "Column 'userTypeID_id' cannot be null")

Now I understand my 'Signal receivers' (as I understand them to be) are missing something to handle this but I am unsure as to what.

Any help would be appreciated and as I'm new, try to explain to me as if i know nothing (because I basically don't haha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to post the full traceback !

When you read the Traceback, you see that this code is part of the traced frames:

```
UserInfo.objects.create(user=instance)
```

The problem with this ? It's just that this is trying to save a UserInfo without userTypeID ! Try this instead:

```
# make your default UserType object
default_user_type, created = UserType.objects.get_or_create(name='default')
UserInfo.objects.create(user=instance, UserTypeID=default_user_type)
```

An alternative would be to just add defaults to columns you don't want to have to fill in when creating an object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if I want to make selecting a type compulsory?

Comment: I also should mention, that the field on the admin page 'usertype' has the valid user types in it but even if I select one and press save, it says the value cannot be null.

Comment: If you want to make it compuslory: then make a view with a form to create the proper object and remove your signal receiver because it won't work. Make your choice, I'm just answering your question. I must say that i find it pretty rude that you have not accepted this correct answer to your question, 3 days later, because a lot of people who just want to help have probably opened this page to see if they could help, seen that the right answer was there, and moved on: you're wasting the community's time and bandwith. This is the answer to "why you get that exception from your signal".

Comment: I didn't accept it because it didn't satisfy my requirements and I wished for more feedback. Only my second post, I am unaware of what the etiquette is here relating to questions but I guess I do now. Thanks

Comment: NP, just go ahead and make another topic for your other question. Avoid editing your question to *change it* after answers have been posted.